# PERL: how to search/replace elegantly beyond carriage return?

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I had trouble googling this, as most people seem to want to know how to remove a carriage return.

The code I have works, but it seems awkward, and I'm missing something. It may be that my original script is designed poorly (I'm checking if one element occurs last, and if so, I need to change it,) but still...it seems I'm missing a quick way to make things smoother.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $a = "This is a string that I concatenate beforehand with carriage returns, so it's hard to separate out.\nThis is the last line I want to track.\nI want to delete this line.";
my $b = $a;

$b =~ s/(track\.).*/$1/g;

print "THIRD LINE STILL THERE\n$b\n\n";

my @c = split(/\n/, $a);
for (0..$#c) { 
   if ($c[$_] =~ /last line/) { 
      $b = join("\n", @c[0..$_]); 
      last; 
   } 
}

print "THIRD LINE GONE. IT WORKS, BUT I THINK THERE MUST BE A BETTER WAY.\n$b\n";
```

Comment: If you're looking for newlines `\n` something like this should work `$a =~ s/\n.*$//g;`

Comment: Note that `\n` is newline; `\r` is for carriage return.

Comment: Actually, it's called a linefeed.  "Newline" is a generic term for anything that's used to separate lines, including linefeed (`\n`), carriage return(`\r`), a carriage return-linefeed pair (`\r\n`), and a few other, more exotic characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a good approach in your code, needing just a little more -- there's no need to iterate.

This removes the last line from a multi-line string.

```
my @lines = split '\n', $line;
pop @lines;
my $text = join '\n', @lines;
```

The [`pop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html) removes the last element from the array.  Or, if you wish to keep `@lines` whole

```
my @lines = split '\n', $line;
my $text = join '\n', @lines[0..$#lines-1];
```

Note that if the "last" line of text itself ends with a newline (so, if it is followed by an empty line), [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) nicely won't return an extra element, since it discards all trailing empty fields in the list that it then returns. So the code above remains the same.

---

Please note comments by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) and [Alan Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20938/alan-moore). From the latter

> "Newline" is a generic term for anything that's used to separate lines, including linefeed (`\n`), carriage return(`\r`), a carriage return-linefeed pair (`\r\n`), and a few other, more exotic characters.

If you were to look for the "*carriage return*", per title, or for other forms of "newline," you'd need to adjust the `\n` in `split` and `join` above. See, for example, their [`Representations on Wikipedia`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations).

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$b =~ s/track\..*/track\./sg;
```

Comment: The key point being the `/s` modifier which [perlreref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html) says: _`s`  match as a Single line - `.` matches `\n`_.

Comment: Probably, "\n" should be instead of "\.".

Answer (score 1):

You can use rindex(), which gets the last index of a position in a string, and combine that with substr(). like this:

```
$b = substr($a, 0, rindex($a, "\\n"));
```

If you want to keep the new line character at the end of your string, then do this:

```
$b = substr($a, 0, rindex($a, "\\n") + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my $string = $a;
$string =~ s/I want to delete[^\n]*\n//gs;
```

There is nothing wrong with splitting the array and iterating over it.  If you wanted to do it in one regex, you can also accomplish it by looking for the target string.

An additional note is to also avoid using `$a` and `$b` as they're often used as internal variables.

Comment: $a and $b are a bad habit of mine. Seeing this in answers on stackoverflow is good motivation to change those variables. And, yes, I'm not morally attached to doing things in one regex, but I often get stuck in methods that work but could be more efficient.

I've worked a while with perl but didn't know about the s option at the end of a search and replace. So that's greta to know in addition.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, it seems what you need is `pop`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $a = "This is a string that I concatenate beforehand with carriage returns, so it's hard to separate out.\nThis is the last line I want to track.\nI want to delete this line.";

my @lines     = split(/\n/, $a);
my $last_line = pop @lines;

print join('\n', @lines) . "\n"; # first two lines
print $last_line . "\n"; # in case you still want to use it ;)
```

Hope this helped